# Subtract 8 hours from time, if time is more 8 hours

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I am trying to create a Timesheet using Google Sheet but this formula `=IF((F8>8),(F8-8),"0")` returns zero even on cells with Total Hours greater than 8

[image]

I have set both Formats to Duration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F), IF(TIMEVALUE(F2:F)>0.3333333333, 
 TEXT(F2:F-0.3333333333, "hh:mm:ss"), 0), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: **F** formatted as `Time` and **G** formatted as `Automatic` or `Time`

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your assistance!!

Comment: I am trying to create a Regular Hours Worked column were data will be taken from Hours Worked. I opted to modify this formula =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F), IF(TIMEVALUE(F2:F)>0.3333333333, 
 TEXT(0.3333333333, "hh:mm:ss"),F2:F), )) But I get this result if hours are less than 8 or 0.3333333333. The formula workes for hours greater than 8

Comment: maybe like this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F), IF(TIMEVALUE(F2:F)>0.3333333333, TEXT(0.3333333333, "hh:mm:ss"),TEXT(F2:F,"hh:mm:ss")),))`

Comment: I get a FALSE reading on all empty cells in the column which I applied this formula, so much that it reaches up to cell 50000.

Comment: @SinethembaGayiza can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14hNGcWHZMj15Pgyk4cIbzQ8ASnQ4V-ilUuxqARQTb1o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: replace your formula with: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F), IF(TIMEVALUE(F2:F)>0.3333333333, 
 TEXT(0.3333333333, "hh:mm:ss"),F2:F),))`

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JE6UBZrp2hjs6MzIpxiAQ07V8gL8UqfbvSKvBhcFYmQ/edit#gid=1787591394&range=G2

Comment: Eish, it's amazing how a comma can give one nightmares. Thank you so much!!